# How do I use Rx to iterate through a series of strings with pauses and fade ins and outs?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, system.reactive

My requirement is take a series of strings from an array starting with the first and after 5 seconds move to the next one whilst fading out and fading in the next string using Rx with XAML in Xamarin. You can assume that this is taking place on a view model that has a 'Message' property and a 'MessageOpacity' property which take text and a decimal between 0 and 1 applicably. You can also assume that I have a Background Scheduler and UiScheduler setup.

I'm fairly new to Rx which will become apparent and have got as far as this so far:

```
var messages = new[] { 
                       "Welcome", 
                       "We are settings things up for you", 
                       "This may take a little while first time" };

Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), Scheduler.BackgroundScheduler)
                  .SelectMany((long arg) => messages)
                  .Buffer(1, 1)
                  .SubscribeOn(Scheduler.UiScheduler)
                  .Subscribe((obj) => 
        {
            Message = obj[0];
        });
```

The above doesn't work, as Buffer isn't working how I expected. Instead it fires 4 strings in rapid succession every 5 seconds rather than stepping through each of the strings.

What I don't understand is how to step through each of the strings in order every 'x seconds' in a correct 'Rx' fashion and (as a bonus for me!) how to subsequently trigger another observable each new message to ramp up and ramp down the opacity from 0 to 1 on each change.

The aim is to achieve the 'windows 10' style screen for when a big update is occurring or whilst the user is waiting for a long operation to complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Zip operator coupled with the Observable.Interval to give the iterative string output you want:

```
[Fact]
public void ShouldIterateThroughStringsEveryFiveSeconds()
{
    TestScheduler scheduler = new TestScheduler();

    string[] messages = new[]
    {
                "Welcome",
                "We are settings things up for you",
                "This may take a little while first time"
    };

    var expected = new[]
    {
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(ReactiveTest.Subscribed + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0).Ticks, "Welcome"),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(ReactiveTest.Subscribed + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5).Ticks, "We are settings things up for you"),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(ReactiveTest.Subscribed + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10).Ticks, "This may take a little while first time"),
        ReactiveTest.OnCompleted<string>(ReactiveTest.Subscribed + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15).Ticks)
    };

    var actual = scheduler.Start(
        // Solution
        () => Observable.Zip(
            messages.ToObservable(),
            Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), scheduler).StartWith(0),
            (text, time) => text),
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20).Ticks
    );

    Assert.Equal(expected, actual.Messages.ToArray());
}
```

Edit: Rather than a second observable for opacity you could combine them like this:

```
[Fact]
public void ShouldIterateThroughStringsEveryFiveSecondsProvidingStringAndOpacity()
{
    TestScheduler scheduler = new TestScheduler();

    string[] messages = new[]
    {
                "Welcome",
                "We are settings things up for you",
                "This may take a little while first time"
    };

    var expected = new[]
    {
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(ReactiveTest.Subscribed + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0).Ticks, Tuple.Create("Welcome", 0.0)),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(ReactiveTest.Subscribed + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5).Ticks, Tuple.Create("We are settings things up for you", 0.5)),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(ReactiveTest.Subscribed + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10).Ticks, Tuple.Create("This may take a little while first time", 1.0)),
        ReactiveTest.OnCompleted<Tuple<string, double>>(ReactiveTest.Subscribed + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15).Ticks)
    };

    var actual = scheduler.Start(
        // Solution
        () => Observable
            .Zip(
                messages.ToObservable(), 
                Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), scheduler).StartWith(0),
                (text, time) => text)
            .Select((text, index) => Tuple.Create(text, Convert.ToDouble(index) / Convert.ToDouble(messages.Length - 1))),
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20).Ticks
    );

    Assert.Equal(expected, actual.Messages.ToArray());
}
```

Note that the opacity of the first element will be zero so you won't see it. You'll probably want to change the math slightly (provide an offset) to scale the opacity from a non-zero value to one.

Hope it helps :0)

Comment: Can you remove the opacity bit that you put in, or alternatively change it to going from invisible to visible and then invisible again for EACH item as per my bonus bit of the question? It should fade in and out per string item rather than across all of them as one single opacity change.

Comment: The top solution excludes the opacity functionality. The animation for each item ought really to be achieved using an animation framework in the view layer (in this case Xamarin) so that it is able to operate at the framerate of the device it is running on. In WPF you'd kick off a storyboard on the property changed event of the string property but not sure how this is achieved using Xamarin.

Comment: agree with you that it should be the remit of the animation framework. Was thinking too blinkered about making Rx do everything for me. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `Observable.Generate`:

```
Observable
    .Generate(
        1,
        x => x < messages.Length,
        x => x + 1,
        x => x,
        x => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0))
    .StartWith(0)
    .Select(x => messages[x])
    .Subscribe((obj) => 
    {
        Message = obj[0];
    });
```

---

You could try this version which ensures that a copy is made of the source array before processing starts - this avoids possible side-effects.

```
Observable
    .Create<string>(o =>
    {
        var ms = messages.ToArray();
        return Observable
            .Generate(
                1,
                x => x < ms.Length,
                x => x + 1,
                x => x,
                x => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0))
            .StartWith(0)
            .Select(x => ms[x])
            .Subscribe(o);
    })
    .Subscribe((obj) =>
    {
        Message = obj[0];
    });
```

Comment: Before you posted this I ended up with this, I'm just wondering which of all of us is clearest: Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), Scheduler.BackgroundScheduler)
       .StartWith(0)
       .Take(messages.Length)
       .Select((arg1, arg2) => messages[arg2])
       .SubscribeOn(Scheduler.UiScheduler)
       .Subscribe((obj) =>

Comment: That's not a terrible option. `Generate` can be written more explicitly. You could even use the value produced with your to avoid the `(arg1, arg2)` syntax.

Comment: Chaps, if I may weigh in here: The 'Generate Index' -> 'Index Lookup' is, in my opinion, a poorer solution. It is not a pure functional expression as the message array isn't passed in but merely closed over by the Select operator. Furthermore as the closure will encompass only the __reference__ to the message array, the expression is non-deterministic as the array is mutable and subject to change. Together I feel this makes the solution less 'reactive'.

Comment: @ibebbs - Would you feel better if I encompassed this in an `Observable.Create` and called a `.ToArray()` within the `Create` to make a local copy of the array?

Comment: How is the array mutable in this situation? Forgive my naive Rx question here, but I was under the impression that C# arrays are not mutable and resizing one for example would result in a new reference.

Comment: @TheSenator - I think he meant that the elements within the array are mutable.

Comment: Ah, fair enough! So which of you is more correct? I'm inclined to go with the fully observable solution of @ibebbs but I'm not in a position of authority to decide who is the most correct in Rx terms.

Comment: @Enigmativity, I could be wrong but I believe that if you call ```.ToArray()``` on an array it doesn't actually copy it as it's already an array (you'll have to use Array.Copy). Either way, I think the logic becomes more opaque as it's hidden by lots of lamdas.

Comment: @TheSenator - both solutions will work, as would innumerable others. While I believe my solution should be preferred for the reasons stated, for now you may want to choose whichever is easier for you to understand and maintain.

Comment: @ibebbs - Calling `.ToArray()` **does** make a copy regardless if it is an array or not.

Comment: @ibebbs - Do keep in mind that the call to `ToObservable()` effectively copies the elements of the source array in the same way that `.ToArray()` does. These solutions are now very similar.

Comment: @Enigmativity, I stand corrected re: the ```.ToArray()``` call. Anyway, rewriting with Observable.Create, copying the array and emitting on a timer should ostensibly do the same thing as my solution. Want to update your answer so that @TheSenator can directly compare?